# While moving quickblox application eclipse to android studio getting error

Tags: android, eclipse, quickblox

While moving quickblox application eclipse to android studio getting error

Image : http://postimg.org/image/t6bkqgaiz/

```
Error
 Process: com.myapp, PID: 1605
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration
            at com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(QBChatService.java:183)
            at com.myapp.ui.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:120)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

===============================

## -->> Here my gradle file using quickblox jar file and other dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':lib_pull_to_refresh')
    compile project(':lib_twowaygridview')


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'    
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-content-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-location-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-ratings-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: add this library in your project

Comment: Does Chat sample work for you? https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/sample-chat/build.gradle

Comment: My project already created in eclipse but here my project move eclipse to studio because in eclipse getting error 65536k multidex. @IgorKhomenko

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add the smack library's jar file to your classpath.

Comment: No, chat sample works fine without this https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/sample-chat/build.gradle